# Can't log on to Windows using Telnet (via PuTTY)

Tags: putty

I try to use PuTTY to connect to a remote computer. (Both computers run Windows.)

The connection is successful, but then PuTTY asks for user name and password.

I'm an admin on the remote computer. I enter my user name on that computer.

```
mrabc@10.xxx.201.xx's password:
Access denied
```

My user name on remote computer 10.xxx.201.xx is mrabc and I enter my Windows password.

Ideas?

Both computers areconnected to the Internet. None is part of a private network.

Comment: Why don't you just use the built-in remote desktop client within Windows?   Why are you choosing to use Putty which isn't the best remote desktop client considering its only going to give you a terminal console.

Comment: What server are you using and is it Telnet or SSH?

Comment: @ Ramhound: this is for educational purposes/

Comment: @gronostaj: SSH

Comment: @SNash *What SSH Server software are you using?*

Comment: @ Darth Android I was thinking Windows 7 pro will contain a SSH server out of the box but clearly it does not ...

Comment: Windows is primarily a GUI-based system and it doesn't have built in SSH server (it has Telnet, but that's a *very* bad idea). I like KpyM Telnet & SSH Server running in SSH mode, it's free for non-commercial use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure because I only use putty to connect to linux. But I think putty is expecting a ssh user/password and not your Windows credentials. you need to configure ssh.  Here is a tutorial setting up a ssh cliënt with openssh and cywgin. It should point you in the right direction. I hope it helps!

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/41560/how-to-get-ssh-command-line-access-to-windows-7-using-cygwin/

Ps,  if  you want to remote desktop to a windows client I recommend checking out remote desktop (which comes default with Windows) or even equally easy to use: teamviewer at http://www.teamviewer.com

Comment: I'm wel familiar with remote desktop. But Putty at least  in theory should also be able to connect to a windows system.

Comment: @SNash as long as you're running an ssh server on the windows box.

Comment: Yup, you're right, but you still need to configure ssh on Windows using openssh or a equivalent. It doesnt come with native ssh support as far as I know.

Comment: Link looks very promising. So I will use it and will update you.

Answer (score 1):

Settings can block access.

"Before users can connect to your Telnet server, you must allow access by adding their user accounts to the TelnetClients group on the Telnet server." https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770895(v=ws.10).aspx

"Connect to a Telnet Server as an Administrator": you can connect "using NTLM authentication" or "using password authentication". https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770640(v=ws.10).aspx

"You can use this procedure to allow users who are members of the local Administrators group that log on by using password authentication **to use** their administrative privileges during a Telnet session." https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754102(v=ws.10).aspx (higher risk, especially across the Internet.)

Telnet only gives a "terminal session", not a remote desktop.
•TeamViewer includes remote desktop and NAT traversal in one package.
•TightVNC includes remote desktop but no NAT traversal, so you'd have to be on the same LAN or routed by separate VPN software.